# Safe AC Halloween shock

Tags: ac

How to with a few volts [5v] give an alternated current safe shock?

To this Halloween i want to make and door that give a shock, but have to be safe and very lite. Like that pens that when you press, it gives you a shock.

ps.: will be one shock in 3 seconds, durning 015 ms
ps2.: i dont want to kill somebody =]

Comment: I've seen more than one person get **really angry** when shocked by one of those gag electric pens or lighters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do two things, only produce periodic shocks with reasonable time between them, and make sure the energy of each shock is limited.  There are rules for things like electric fences along these lines, but a Halloween gizmo shouldn't produce anywhere near the shock of a electric fence.

The best way to do this electrically I think is similar to a boost converter.  A coil is connected between the 5V rail and ground thru a transistor switch.  Most of the time the switch is off, no current is flowing, and there is no high voltage.  When you want to produce a shock pulse, turn the transistor on for a fixed time to charge up the inductor to just below saturation.  When the transistor turns off, the inductor voltage will spike.  The total energy will be limited by what the inductor can store.  You probaly want to put a clamp on the inductor to limit the voltage to some maximum level.  This also limits the voltage the transistor switch sees.  That transistor must be rated to at least that voltage.

Comment: I'd add that you want this circuit to be battery powered.  A pair of D-cell batteries should power it all night.  The reason for this is to isolate the doorknob from the AC power.  Should something bad happen, there is only so much damage that a pair of batteries can do.    With that in mind, don't use a car battery...

Comment: @David: Yes good point.  I was assuming this was battery powered, but it's good to say that explicitly.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I don't think I've said anything wrong.  If someone disagrees, they should at least say what they find incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

I would be wary about shocking people without their consent. Even a small shock could be dangerous.

Instead, why not use a high frequency buzzer to give a tingle to the hand.

Answer (score 4):

This is a terrible idea for a project.  There is no way that you can guarantee that a shock given by any circuit you could reasonably construct at home would be absolutely safe.  Sure, you might be able to construct a current-limited circuit that would deliver a "safe" shock to most people...but what about people who have pacemakers? Implanted defibrillators?

In any case, I'm pretty sure that such a device could be considered a "booby trap", even if it's not designed to kill or maim.  Such devices are illegal in all 50 states and many foreign countries.

In short: causing any type of injury to a person without their explicit consent is exercising poor judgement.